# NavigateAsync in constructor not working after absolute NavigateAsync

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin.forms, prism

OK so, I have defaultPage, loginPage and pinCodePage.

I navigate to defaultPage from the OnInitialized method. The desired behaviour from here is that I check if they are logged in, if they aren't then navigate to the login page. After the log in page they will have to set a pin so navigate to the pinCodePage then once complete back to default page. Every time the app is opened (except resume) it should prompt for the pin code so navigate there from defaultPage. The final thing is that they can log out on the pinCodePage which should take them to the loginPage.

I figured the easiest way to do this was to have a check in the defaultPage constructor that would navigate to loginPage if not loggedIn or to the pinCodePage if they are. (I didn't think OnNavigatedTo was good because it would trigger upon coming back from the pinCode page and loop without some logic stopping it.) The only issue was that using GoBackAsync didn't hit the constructor again. To solve this I tried absolute navigation from the loginPage to the defaultPage. This absolute navigate from loginPage to defaultPage worked (after much puzzling over the syntax for using the URI, it's not explained anywhere) but defaultPage wouldn't navigate to pinCodePage despite NavigateAsync being called in the defaultPage constructor.

**Anyone able to explain why this NavigateAsync won't work after the absolute navigation?**

Answer (score 0):

> The only issue was that using GoBackAsync didn't hit the constructor again

Of course not. When you go back you are not creating a new instance of the page but rather going back to an existing page.

> after much puzzling over the syntax for using the URI, it's not explained anywhere

For your reference, the absolute URI syntax is shown in the documentation:

https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Documentation/Xamarin.Forms/3-NavigationService.md#navigating

My recommendation is not to do any navigation within a ctor of a Page.  Why have a DefaultPage if it is just going to navigate to another page immediately on app startup?  It sounds like you should take them to the PinCodePage after they login, then when that is setup navigate to an absolute URI for the DefaultPage.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the reply and for prism forms I really like it.

I knew the GoBackAsync wouldn't work, I was just explaining the situation.

As for the URI comment, as a junior programmer it wasn't obvious to me what the URI format should be. I'm not trying to hate just giving perspective for things that others might have trouble with. Seeing what is essentially a url for a webpage just confused me. I didn't realise the scheme and anything before the 3rd slash is basically irrelevant and it's about what you have after the slash.

Comment: The reason I have the defaultPage as the first page is because in my mind login and the pin code are modal operations that should be presented over whatever the first page should be. If this is incorrect then I'll happily correct my mistake. Also, why exactly is navigation in a constructor bad?

As a bonus question while I have you here, is there ever any reason to await an async navigate call?

Comment: Is there any acceptable way to call navigation when a viewmodel is created then rather than having to use onnavigatedto?